# Cannot access SOAP xml nested id= attribute using Savon 2

Tags: ruby, xml, soap, savon

In the soap response below (from SoapUI), under the parent `SearchForReservationResponse` tag, I am trying to pull out the values of `Reservation id`, `Restaurant id` and `Location id` with Savon 2.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <SearchForReservationResponse xmlns="http://schemas.livebookings.net/OneFormat/Aggregator/Internal/1/0/">
         <Reservation id="34639536" status="Confirmed">
            <DiningDateAndTime>2015-07-01T17:00:00</DiningDateAndTime>
            <Restaurant id="25200">
               <Name>Eat Food - UK Demo Website - Bookatable.com</Name>
               <Location id="35839">
                  <Name>Bar</Name>
               </Location>
            </Restaurant>
            <Size>2</Size>
            <Created>2015-07-01T13:22:17.41</Created>
            <SessionId>DINNER</SessionId>
            <FirstName>John</FirstName>
            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
            <ConfirmationNumber>JWRW5HR5</ConfirmationNumber>
            <AllowedToCancelOnline>true</AllowedToCancelOnline>
            <RestaurantPhoneNumber type="Main">+44 7951300529</RestaurantPhoneNumber>
         </Reservation>
      </SearchForReservationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Below is my attempt for trying to access `Reservation id`. After a lot of googling I found that the new Savon 2 syntax uses @attrib, but I keep getting errors as I think I am not using this Ruby nested hash syntax correctly - I find it very confusing and am fairly new to Ruby. If you could help me out here it would be much appreciated!

```
require 'savon'

class SearchReservation
  attr_reader :reservation_id

  def client
    client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://example-wsdl-url", follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
  end

  def main_method(confirm_number, email)
    message = {'ConfirmationNumber' => "JWRW5HR5", 'EMail' => "jon@" }
    response = client.call(:search_for_reservation, message: message)
    data = response.body(:search_for_reservation_response => { @attrib => {:reservation => :id} })   
    if data
      @reservation_id = data[:id]
  end
end

end

search = SearchReservation.new
puts search.main_method("JWRW5HR5", "jon@")
```

N.B. the email value jon@ doesn't have to be a valid email address (used just for testing purposes) - it returns a valid response in SoapUI.

My last syntax error trace in the terminal/console:

```
/~/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-2.11.1/lib/savon/response.rb:36:in `body': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
    from search.rb:13:in `main_method'
    from search.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: `puts response.body` will lead you to the proper direction. I bet `JSON.parse(response.body)` will give you a ready-to-use hash.

Comment: thanks @mudasobwa that was really good advice, but how do I represent the objects I want to extract as instance variables for later use in a rails app. This is how I did it before: https://gist.github.com/daneasterman/90bb3d29cefba38e5e10

Comment: To clarify: how should I represent the values (usually strings) of the keys, for example: `:name=>"Eat Food - UK Demo Website - Bookatable.com"` - can I represent this as a simple variable of my choosing like restarurant_name

Comment: It’s totally up to you: you might even assign `@all_data_from_service = JSON.parse(response.body)` and use it as a hash, or assign everything on per variable basis, like `@restrnt_name = parsed_response[:name]`.

Comment: JSON.parse doesn't work as it gives this error: `/Users/dan14/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:155:in initialize: no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)`

Comment: will response.to_hash achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: It sounds like `response.body` is already a hash. `puts response.body.class` and `puts response.to_hash` should finally shed a light on what to use. Sorry for these “approx” hints, but I have no clue about `savon` itself and I can’t assume what data types it returns.

Comment: No worries, it's not just specific things to Savon, it's also specific to the SOAP api I'm trying to consume. I think JSON.parse doesn't work as the datetime info strangely remains as xml and is not converted to Ruby-friendly symbols. This is how it looks in terminal: `{:dining_date_and_time=>#<DateTime: 2015-07-01T17:00:00+00:00 ((2457205j,61200s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>` I need this info as an instance variable in my app. Any ideas how to convert it?

Comment: If this helps all of the returned data from response.body looks like this:

Comment: It is already a hash, so `@var_name_of_my_choice = whatever_was_printed_above[:dining_date_and_time]` would do a trick.

Answer (score 0):

My final solution pulling out all the values I need. Of note: even though dining_date_and_time was presented as xml when putting response.body, when it is extracted using `@dining_date_and_time = data[:dining_date_and_time]` the date and time values get printed cleanly. This is key once porting to a fully-fledged Rails app.

Despite all the discussion online about attributes, ids within an xml tag can be pulled by just ensuring you are far enough down the "tree" (ie. location id falls under location tag) and then specifying the key: in this case the api displays it as :@id for each nested case.

N.B, this only returns the last value called each time in console. But all values should be pulled in views once integrated into Rails. (Hopefully!)

```
require 'savon'

class SearchClass

  def client
  client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://wsdl-example-url", follow_redirects: :follow_redirects)
  end

  def return_data(confirm_number, email)
    message = {'ConfirmationNumber' => confirm_number, 'EMail' => email  }
    response = client.call(:search_for_reservation, message: message)
    data = response.to_hash[:search_for_reservation_response][:reservation]
    @reservation_id = data[:@id]
    @dining_date_and_time = data[:dining_date_and_time]
    @size = data[:size]
    @session_id = data[:session_id]
    @first_name = data[:first_name]
    @last_name = data[:last_name]
    @confirm_number = data[:confirmation_number]
    @allowed_to_cancel_online = data[:allowed_to_cancel_online]
    @restaurant_phone_number = data[:restaurant_phone_number]

    data2 = response.to_hash[:search_for_reservation_response][:reservation][:restaurant]
    @restaurant_id = data2[:@id]
    @restaurant_name = data2[:name]

    data3 = response.to_hash[:search_for_reservation_response][:reservation][:restaurant][:location]
    @location_id = data3[:@id]
    @location_name = data3[:name]

  end  

end

search = SearchClass.new
puts search.return_data("JWRW5HR5", "jon@")
```